# Is order of ports in target definition significant (relational target)

Tags: sql-server-2012, informatica, informatica-powercenter

New to Informatica and need to clarify this-
Transformation type: Target (SQL Server relational)
Is the order of ports from top to bottom significant when inserting records into a SQL Server DB table? Will there be insert failures if Informatica target port order does not follow the column order of the DB table?

Example:
Informatica 9.5 Target Definition port order:

```
+-------+--------+  
|Port   |DataType|
+-------+--------+
|Name   |varchar |
|Addr   |varchar |
|Phone  |varchar |
+-------+--------+
```

SQL Server column order:

```
+-------+--------+  
|Column |DataType|
+-------+--------+
|Name   |varchar |
|Phone  |varchar |
|Addr   |varchar |
+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not cause any issue as the insert query generated by Informatica will be like below which will work just fine:

```
insert into tablename(Name, Addr, Phone) values ('abc','xyz','123')
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't but mapping the ports interchangeably will have issues on the data or it will throw an error when datatype does not matched :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the port you link to the target. If corresponding ports are linked to the target, informatica generates the insert statement as per order in target definition.

Answer (score 0):

No you will not face any insert issues. Only the mapping pipeline should be linked to the relevant target ports. In your case there will be no any issues even the pipeline is interchanged as all your data types are same. It may be due to some transformation logic issue or you may failed to provide data base connection in the session task. It will be helpful if you post your session logs.